# docker-compose not being able to connect to Prisma/client

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, prisma

I have this app which works with PostgreSQL + Prisma on my machine. But when I want to run it with docker-compose, I get the below error:

```
db                          | waiting for server to start....2023-09-02 13:14:05.101 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.104 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.111 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-02 13:14:04 UTC
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.121 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db                          |  done
db                          | server started
db                          | CREATE DATABASE
db                          | 
db                          | 
db                          | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db                          | 
db                          | waiting for server to shut down...2023-09-02 13:14:05.347 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db                          | .2023-09-02 13:14:05.349 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.352 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.354 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.356 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.494 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 918 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.069 s, sync=0.065 s, total=0.140 s; sync files=301, longest=0.021 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4223 kB, estimate=4223 kB
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.506 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
db                          |  done
db                          | server stopped
db                          | 
db                          | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db                          | 
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.586 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.4 (Debian 15.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.588 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.589 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.591 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.597 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-02 13:14:05 UTC
db                          | 2023-09-02 13:14:05.610 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | src/prisma/prisma.service.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@prisma/client' or its corresponding type declarations.
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 3 import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
ft_transcendence-backend-1  |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | src/prisma/prisma.service.ts:13:20 - error TS2339: Property '$connect' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 13         await this.$connect();
ft_transcendence-backend-1  |                       ~~~~~~~~
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | src/user/user.service.ts:10:28 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 10         return this.prisma.user.create({ data: userData });
ft_transcendence-backend-1  |                               ~~~~
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | src/user/user.service.ts:14:28 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 14         return this.prisma.user.fields
ft_transcendence-backend-1  |                               ~~~~
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | Found 4 error(s).
ft_transcendence-backend-1  | 
frontend                    | (node:25
```

in this error part of my code is not recognized due to lacking prisma/client.
Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
     - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - front_volume:/frontend
    networks:
      - webapp


  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 5500:5500
    environment:
      - DB_URL=postgresql://swypf:secret@db:5432/postgres_db?schema=public
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/backend/src
    networks:
      - database
      - webapp
    depends_on:
      - db
  #    command: ['./start.sh' ]

  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=swypf
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres_db
    networks:
      - database

volumes:
  db_volume:
  front_volume:
networks:
  database:
    driver: bridge
  webapp:
    driver: bridge
```

and this is start.sh:

```
npx prisma db push
npm run start
```

and this is my dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
RUN npm install -g typescript
WORKDIR /backend

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate
RUN chmod 777 start.sh


EXPOSE 5500
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

for reference, this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.2.0",
    "postgres": "^3.3.5",
    "prisma": "^5.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.11",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

When I check dependencies, prisma/client is already there. To be sure i removed node-modules and installed everything again. But still I get this error.